# Find a recursive formula for $a_n$, $n ≥ 2$, in terms of $a_{n−1}$ and $a_{n−2}$, where $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1$

Tags: power-series, recursion, recursive-algorithms

Find a recursive formula for $a_n$, $n\ge 2$, in terms of $a_{n-1}$ and $a_{n-2}$, where $a_0=0$, $a_1=1$, $a_2=-1$.

The power series is

$$\sum\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}$$

And can anyone help with mathjax, I can't seem to get a hang of it!

Comment: Have I correctly interpreted your expression? Also, please include the question in the body, not just in the title. I’ll take care of it this time.

Comment: yes that's perfect thank you!

Comment: There’s a basic MathJax reference [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: How are $a_n$ and the series related?

Comment: the problem set has steps to the overall problem, and I'm not sure if this information might help in finding the recursive formula